# How to update 2 tables using sql in php?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have `2 tables` but when updated, the data from both tables doesn't work. I also have 2 tables where **the first table does not have a foreign key,** while **the second table has a foreign key.**
for example **the skb table** **as the first table** does not have a foreign key, while **the pengikut_skb table** as **the second table** has a foreign key.

skb table:

**id_skb (PK)**

---

pengikut_skb table:

**id_pengikut_skb (PK)**

**id_skb (FK)**

---

```
$koneksi= mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "","test");

    $query1 = ("UPDATE skb SET nl='$nl', ttl='$ttl', jk='$jk', pekerjaan='$pekerjaan', status='$status', agama='$agama', nktp='$nktp', kewa='$kewa', aktp='$aktp', aa='$aa', at='$at', mbp='$mbp', dk='$dk', lb='$lb', jp='$jp', nskl='$nskl', dp='$dp', jenis_kep='$jenis_kep', mb='$mb', syarat_lampiran='$syarat_lampiran', kode_surat1='$kode_surat1', kode_surat2='$kode_surat2', kode_surat3='$kode_surat3', buku_tamu='$buku_tamu', kode_surat4='$kode_surat4', tahun_kode_surat='$tahun_kode_surat', riwayat_kelola='$riwayat_kelola' WHERE id_skb ='$id_skb'");
    $oke1=mysqli_query($koneksi,$query1);

    $query2 = (" UPDATE pengikut_skb SET nama_atau_jumlah_pengikut='$nama_atau_jumlah_pengikut', umur_pengikut='$umur_pengikut', pekerjaan_pengikut='$pekerjaan_pengikut', keterangan_pengikut='$keterangan_pengikut', nama_pengikut='$nama_pengikut', umur_pengikut2='umur_pengikut2', pekerjaan_pengikut2='$pekerjaan_pengikut2', keterangan_pengikut2='$keterangan_pengikut2', nama_pengikut2='$nama_pengikut2', umur_pengikut3='$umur_pengikut3', pekerjaan_pengikut3='$pekerjaan_pengikut3', keterangan_pengikut3='$keterangan_pengikut3', WHERE id_pengikut_skb = '$id_pengikut_skb'");
    $oke2=mysqli_query($koneksi,$query2);
```

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Are you getting an error message?

Comment: Also if you're not going to use a framework that handles this for you, please check this out for safer queries: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: @Citizen sorry "doesnt work" i mean my data nothing updated in the tables. maybe my query doesnt right.

Comment: Is there an error message? Please post the output of "echo $query1". Seeing the actual query would be helpful. Any number of things in your variables could be creating a problem since you're not securely creating them. For instance, if there are any single quotes in your variables it can break your query.

Comment: See about sql injection and the importance of prepared and bound queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
UPDATE skb 
  JOIN pengikut_skb USING (id_skb)
SET skb.column1 = '$value1'
  , pengikut_skb.column2 = '$value2'
-- and so on for each column in each table which must be updated
WHERE pengikut_skb.id_pengikut_skb = '$id_pengikut_skb'
-- and so on - all conditions which defines what record(s) must be updated in each table
--  AND skb.column3 = $value3
--  AND pengikut_skb.column4 = $value4
```

You do not need to specify `skb.id_skb` value as in your 1st query because it is defined by `$id_pengikut_skb` value which is used in 2nd query.

Answer (score 0):

In the second query, you are not updating the value of id_skb which is the foreign key of your table. It should have some value in the record which is present in the skb table. It might be one reason that your query is not updating the table. Or if you have set the foreign key as null by default then some other reason can be there.

Hope this helps..